# How to scrape item with no reference or name attribute?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

Hi I am really new at scrapy scrape I tried the basic code but this is one kinda unique and how I tried different approach here. How can I get the number of like, love and informative here
https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/

here's my code

```
<ul class="dark_postrating_outputlist">
<li>
<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Informative x <strong>1</strong>
</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Like x <strong>1</strong>
</li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to get the specific item inside  
I have tried this

```
response.css('ul.dark_postrating_outputlist i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up strong::text').extract_first()
```

But its not working, any idea please? thank you

Comment: what means `not working` ? Show your result and what result you expected.

Comment: I am trying it on scrapy shell but it doesn't show any error nor result just blank, or if i will put extract() it will just show "[]"

Comment: how about `response.css('strong::text').extract()` or `response.css('ul.dark_postrating_outputlist strong::text').extract()` If you need many results then don't use `extract_first()`

Comment: your problem is `<i>` - `<string>` is NOT inside `<i>` so don't use `i` in css (you can get two elements and later use `items[0]` and `items[1]`) or use `~`  like  `"i ~ strong"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get the required content:

```
import scrapy

class TeslamotorsclubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "teslamotorsclub"
    start_urls = ["https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css("[id^='fc-post-']"):
            author = item.css(".author::text").get()
            like = item.css(".fa-thumbs-o-up + strong::text").get()
            love = item.css(".fa-heart-o + strong::text").get()
            informative = item.css(".fa-info-circle + strong::text").get()
            yield {"author":author,"like":like,"love":love,"informative":informative}
```

Partial output:

```
{'author': 'Unpilot', 'like': '1', 'love': '4', 'informative': '1'}
{'author': 'UnknownSoldier', 'like': '7', 'love': '2', 'informative': '1'}
{'author': 'SpaceCash', 'like': '2', 'love': '15', 'informative': '2'}
{'author': 'gene', 'like': '45', 'love': '18', 'informative': '1'}
{'author': 'engle', 'like': '31', 'love': '5', 'informative': '15'}
{'author': 'Unpilot', 'like': '11', 'love': '3', 'informative': None}
{'author': 'SebastianR', 'like': '3', 'love': None, 'informative': None}
{'author': 'Buckminster', 'like': '1', 'love': '4', 'informative': None}
```

Comment: Wow thank you @sim for your help you just gave it all

Comment: Hi @sim I wanted to scrape all the items inside the page why I just get 1 output?

Comment: What do you mean by one output? I'm updating my answer with few of the results I'm having.

Comment: Thank you I just have wrong indention, even spacing and indention is very sensitive thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can add some more specific selector to separate "likes" and "informative" data. Check this example:

```
>>> txt = """<ul class="dark_postrating_outputlist">
...  <li>
...  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Informative x <strong>1</strong>
...  </li>
...  <li> 
...  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Like x <strong>2</strong>
...  </li>
...  </ul>"""
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.css('ul.dark_postrating_outputlist li:contains("Informative") strong::text').get()
u'1'
>>> sel.css('ul.dark_postrating_outputlist li:contains("Like") strong::text').get()
u'2'
```

Here you can get your numbers separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath instead of CSS:

```py
response.xpath('//ul[@class="dark_postrating_outputlist"]/li[//i[contains()"fa-thumbs-o-up"]]/strong/text()').get()
```